# Copying files across S3 buckets with different IAM's

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3

I am copying files across accounts with different IAM's with 2 boto sessions. Each session functions as expected. I was hoping the copy operation will work fine using the SourceClient parameter but it does not. Code follows , IAM and paths redacted.

```
import boto3 as boto


session_aero =   boto.session.Session(aws_access_key_id='AMI_1',
aws_secret_access_key='SEC_1')
s3_aero = session_aero.client('s3')
s3_aero_resource = session_aero.resource('s3')
src = s3_aero_resource.Bucket('bucket-1')




session_cube = boto.session.Session("AMI_2","SEC_2")
s3_cube = session_cube.client('s3')

for tif in src.objects.filter(Prefix='file/prefix/'):
     copy_source = {'Bucket':'bucket-1','Key':tif.key}
     s3_cube.copy(copy_source,'bucket-2',tif.key,SourceClient=s3_aero)
```

Comment: Just for reference, `SourceClient` is mentioned on [the boto3 S3 page](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/s3.html). It says "To do a managed copy where the region of the source bucket is different than the region of the final bucket, provide a SourceClient that shares the same region as the source bucket." So, the question is whether the SourceClient can have different credentials as well as a different region.